# How do I select the ID of input datepicker in jquery as soon as I select the date?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker calendar (jQuery library) that is populated when I click on an input text field.
I want to know the ID of this input text as soon as I select the date on the calendar.

Ex. 
Input text:

```
<input type="text" class="add-event-form" id="backup-date-1" name="backup-date-1" />
```

When I click on this input the calendar shows as a tooltip, let's say I select a day on the calendar. How do I get the id `backup-date-1` ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
$("input").on("click", function() {
    alert( $(this).prop("id") );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xf7a2/)